# problem re-loading index from filebeat in elasticsearch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using the ELK stack (more ELG stack as I am using Grafana as the front end instead of kibana for personal reasons). I am using Filebeat to send the logs file to Logstash which are then stored in Elasticsearch and displayed through Grafana. I have used [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-getting-started.html) for the setup.

Now when I have added another path in the `filebeat.yml` configuration file and then deleted the previous indices in Elasticsearch and then loaded the template again through the following command,

```
filebeat setup --template -E output.logstash.enabled=false -E 'output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]'
```

the index is not registered in elasticsearch and

curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v

shows no index in Elasticsearch. After checking the Filebeat logs I found the following error:

```
2018-06-05T10:08:32.228+0500 INFO instance/beat.go:468 Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/var/log/filebeat]
2018-06-05T10:08:32.229+0500 INFO instance/beat.go:475 Beat UUID: edf1a2c9-0d7d-4c8a-9823-30bf64b72a4f
2018-06-05T10:08:32.229+0500 INFO instance/beat.go:213 Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 6.2.4
2018-06-05T10:08:32.229+0500 INFO elasticsearch/client.go:145 Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2018-06-05T10:08:32.230+0500 INFO pipeline/module.go:76 Beat name: vbras
2018-06-05T10:08:32.231+0500 INFO elasticsearch/client.go:145 Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2018-06-05T10:08:32.245+0500 INFO elasticsearch/client.go:690 Connected to Elasticsearch version 6.2.4
```

**`2018-06-05T10:08:32.249+0500 INFO template/load.go:73 Template already exists and will not be overwritten.`**

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From [latest version documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html), it is possible to replace index template with following configuration keys:

```
setup.template.overwrite: true
setup.template.enabled: true
```